# Is this possible with mysql?

Tags: mysql

First of all: sorry for the title, but maybe I will find a better one later.

I asked this some minutes ago, but since I was not able to describe what I want I try it again :)

Here is my table structure:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b25f9/37

The table is used to store user sessions.

Out of this I would like to generate a stacked bar chart that should show how many active users I have. My idea was that I group the users based on their online-times of the last days like this
[image]

Lets say its friday:

- Group B: Users that were online thursday (and today)
- Group C: Users that were not online thursday but wednesday (and today)
- Group D: Users that were not online thursday or wednesday but tuesday (and today)
- Group E: Users that were not online thursday, wednesday or tuesday but last monday, sunday or saturday (and today)
- Group A: Users that do not match the other groups (but were only today)
- I only want to know the number of users in those groups (for a specific day)
- a user can only be in ONE of these groups (for the same day)

Comment: if the user was online to day and yesterday, the count would be 1 or 2?

Comment: This would just count as 1 for the first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Another Update:** Accidently (by copy&paste) had `starttime = ... or starttime = ...` but it should be `starttime = ... or endtime = ...`

**UPDATE:**

To explain my query in more detail (in the final query there are even more comments):

First we simply got

```
SELECT
...
FROM gc_sessions s
WHERE DATE(starttime) = CURDATE() OR DATE(endtime) = CURDATE()
```

That's nothing more like saying "give me all users whose session started today or ended today". Having to consider those two times again and again makes the query a bit clumsy, but actually it's not that complicated.

So, usually we would use the COUNT() function to count something, obviously, but since we want "conditional counting", we simply use the SUM() function and tell it when to add 1 and when not.

```
SUM (CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a_column_name
```

The SUM() function examines now each row in the result set of sessions from today. So for each user in this result set we look if this user was online the date we specify. It doesn't matter how many times he/she was online, so for performance reasons we use `EXISTS`. With `EXISTS` you can specify a subquery which stops as soon as something is found, so it doesn't matter what it returns when something is found, as long as it's not `NULL`. So don't get confused why I selected `1`. In the subquery we have to connect the user which is currently examined from the outer query with the user from the inner query (subquery) and specify the time window. If all criterias meet count 1 else 0 like explained before.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN 
         EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gc_sessions sub_s WHERE s.user = sub_s.user 
                  AND ((date(starttime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                       OR (date(endtime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS todayAndYesterday,
```

Then we make a column for each condition and voila, you have all you need in one query. So with your updated question your criteria has changed, we just have to add more rules:

```
SELECT
/*this is like before*/
SUM(CASE WHEN 
         EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gc_sessions sub_s WHERE s.user = sub_s.user 
                  AND ((date(starttime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                       OR (date(endtime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FridayAndThursday,
SUM(CASE WHEN 
         EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gc_sessions sub_s WHERE s.user = sub_s.user 
                  AND ((date(starttime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
                       OR (date(endtime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY)))
         /*this one here is a new addition, since you don't want to count the users that were online yesterday*/
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gc_sessions sub_s WHERE s.user = sub_s.user 
                  AND ((date(starttime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                       OR (date(endtime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FridayAndWednesdayButNotThursday,
SUM(CASE WHEN 
         EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gc_sessions sub_s WHERE s.user = sub_s.user 
                  AND ((date(starttime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY) /* minus 3 days to get tuesday*/
                       OR (date(endtime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)))
         /*this is the same as before, we check again that the user was not online between today and tuesday, but this time we really use BETWEEN for convenience*/
         AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gc_sessions sub_s WHERE s.user = sub_s.user 
                  AND ((date(starttime) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                       OR (date(endtime) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FridayAndTuesdayButNotThursdayAndNotWednesday,
.../*and so on*/
FROM gc_sessions s
WHERE DATE(starttime) = CURDATE() OR DATE(endtime) = CURDATE()
```

So, I hope you get the idea now. Any more questions? Feel free to ask.

**end of update**

*Answer to previous version of question:*

```
select 
SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gc_sessions sub_s WHERE s.user = sub_s.user 
                      AND ((date(starttime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                           OR (date(starttime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS todayAndYesterday,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gc_sessions sub_s WHERE s.user = sub_s.user 
                      AND ((date(starttime) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                           OR (date(starttime) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS todayAndYesterdayOrTheDayBeforeYesterday,
SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gc_sessions sub_s WHERE s.user = sub_s.user 
                      AND ((date(starttime) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                           OR (date(starttime) BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS todayAndWithinTheLastWeek
from gc_sessions s
where date(starttime) = CURDATE()
or date(endtime) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: Wow, a complex route. @@. You join your sql oftenly like this? All in one.

Comment: @K.D. Ooops, got the `BETWEEN` parameters switched. Should work now.

Comment: @mjb It looks complex, but with a better formatting it actually isn't.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I have just one question: If I substract the interval of one day this won't tell me how many users were only at a specific day, right? Because I'm thinking about using this to create a 30-day chart to show this results for each day.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get the question. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: Sorry for my english.. I mean that I want to receive the same results no matter what time it is. The results should be same as long as its still the same day. Your query is not "sorting" by date itself but by hours what would be wrong for me if I want to offer a statistic that should display those informations by dates. Can you follow me?

Comment: Now I'm even more confused :) "The results should be same as long as its still the same day." It is, with the `DATE()` function we're stripping the time. I'm "sorting" by hours? The query will always have just one row as result. What do you mean by sorting? And where come hours into play?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to explain in more detailed:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566239/difficult-mysql-query

Comment: The key point of this answer is not the completed baked working SQL, it is the usage of specific key words like `SUM(CASE WHEN EXISTS CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END OR BETWEEN` and more @@! (< my eyes and sweat) in the answer. The fishing skill, not the fished result.

Comment: @mjb Updated my answer and explained a bit more. Hope this helps.

Comment: @K.D. Got confused who asked for clarification and who asked the actual question. Anyway, updated my answer, hope this solves your problem.

Comment: @K.D. Any feedback? Not what you're looking for? More questions?

Comment: @K.D. We invested work and time in answering your question. So I think it's kind of rude when you don't even give feedback.

Comment: @tombom Of course I will answer as soon as I find time to test this.. thanks very much for your effort

Comment: 2 days did not check in, missed the message. OMG, really fantastic logic. thanks you so much for sharing the knowledge of sub-routine/sub-queries. MySQL really can perform certain complex queries, in stead of calculating it manually in programming. If we want to do programming to perform above task. Very sure that there are lots more lines to code to archive that. I am now aware of the usage of `SUM()` and `CASE WHEN EXISTS`. I can see now why you said there is no need to create extra table. Previously, I need, this is because I can't perform this complex logic query.

Comment: I am truely appreciate for the effort of sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on session table, I suggest you to create separate table, which stores 2 fields, date and user_id. 
Every time user logs-in you need to insert new entry into this table.

This way you will be able to retrieve all the 3 requirement of yours.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. I have posted an example as answer.

Comment: This info is already stored in the sessions table. What is the point in creating a different table?

Answer (score 1):

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`user_login_history` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Once a user login, check whether he/she has login today or not:

```
select count(*) from user_login_history where 
userid = 1 and `date` = '2013-01-28 00:00:00';
```

If the returned value is 1, means he/she has login today. no changes needed.
but, if the returned value is 0, means he/she has not login today. So record it down.

```
insert into user_login_history(userid,`date`)values(1,'2013-01-28 00:00:00');
```

Q1. How many users were online TODAY that were also online YESTERDAY?

```
select count(*) from user_login_history u where 
u.`date` = '2013-01-28 00:00:00' and 
(
select count(*) from user_login_history v where 
v.`date` = '2013-01-27 00:00:00' and 
v.userid = u.userid
) = 1;
```

Q2. How many users were online TODAY that were also online within in the last TWO DAYS

```
select count(*) from user_login_history u where 
u.`date` = '2013-01-28 00:00:00' and
(
select count(*) from user_login_history v where
v.`date` >= '2013-01-26 00:00:00' and
v.`date` <= '2013-01-27 00:00:00' and
v.userid = u.userid
) > 0;
```

Q3. How many users were online TODAY that were also online within the last 7 DAYS

```
select count(*) from user_login_history u where 
u.`date` = '2013-01-28 00:00:00' and
(
select count(*) from user_login_history v where
v.`date` >= '2013-01-21 00:00:00' and
v.`date` <= '2013-01-27 00:00:00' and
v.userid = u.userid
) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

For yesterday

```
select id from gc_sessions where id in 
( 
  select id 
  from gc_sessions 
  where starttime > subdate(current_date, 2)
  and endtime < subdate(current_date, 1)
)

and starttime > subdate(current_date, 1);
```

For 2 Days

```
select id from gc_sessions where id in 
( 
  select id 
  from gc_sessions 
  where starttime > subdate(current_date, 3)
  and endtime < subdate(current_date, 1)
)

and starttime > subdate(current_date, 1);
```

For 7 Days

```
select id from gc_sessions where id in 
( 
  select id 
  from gc_sessions 
  where starttime > subdate(current_date, 8)
  and endtime < subdate(current_date, 1)
)

and starttime > subdate(current_date, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have provided a newer version with your code but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a subquery that loads the data from the specified range (eg, 1day/2day/7days) and compares it with the data for the current day.

```
set @range = 7;
select * from gc_sessions
WHERE user in (SELECT user from gc_sessions
where starttime between subdate(current_date, @range) AND subdate(current_date, 1))

AND starttime > subdate(current_date, 0)
```

Where `@range` holds information about the number of days. See your expanded sql fiddle at - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9584b/24

Comment: That is working as expected.  It returns all the users who have logged in since `@now` (due to the `>`).  If you want all users that have logged in on only `@now` then use something like `AND starttime between subdate(@now, 0) and @now + interval 1 day` for the last part of the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT today.user
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT today.ip) ip
       FROM gc_sessions today
       JOIN gc_sessions yesterday
         ON DATE(yesterday.starttime) = DATE(today.starttime) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        AND today.user = yesterday.user
      WHERE DATE(today.starttime) = '2013-01-10'
      GROUP 
         BY today.user;
```