# Difficult mysql query?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is this possible with mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561430/is-this-possible-with-mysql)

First of all: sorry for the title, but maybe I will find a better one later.

I asked this some minutes ago, but since I was not able to describe what I want I try it again :)

Here is my table structure:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b25f9/37

The table is used to store user sessions.

Out of this I would like to generate a stacked bar chart that should show how many active users I have. My idea was that I group the users based on their online-times of the last days like this
[image]

Lets say its friday:

- Group B: Users that were online thursday (and today)
- Group C: Users that were not online thursday but wednesday (and today)
- Group D: Users that were not online thursday or wednesday but tuesday (and today)
- Group E: Users that were not online thursday, wednesday or tuesday but last monday, sunday or saturday (and today)
- Group A: Users that do not match the other groups (but were only today)
- I only want to know the number of users in those groups (for a specific day)
- a user can only be in ONE of these groups (for the same day)

Comment: Show us your current attempt at a SQL query.

Comment: I have no idea, thats why I want to know if its possible at all

Comment: It looks possible to me.  It's basically an "aggregate" query, using GROUP BY, COUNT, and HAVING clauses with date ranges.

Comment: what means idletime =0 ? and idletime = 25?

Comment: Thats not important. Its just if I want to sum up any onlinetimes for users.